# Solr fields sorting by 2 fields treated as one

Tags: sorting, solr

I am bit struggling with one topic for custom fields.

By default all documents have field *price_double* to keep default price.
Next I got requirement that there should also be customer prices defined per document, so I have added fields like *price_[customerId]_double* next to default one.
These fields are optional and number of these fields per doc varies. When I get documents, if custom one exists I fetch it as default and use on storefront. that functionality is handled in app code.

Then I got requirement about sorting and treat price as ranged facet. But to have same behavior like custom price is  default. Meaning, when I sort default and custom prices these 2 fields should be treated as one so result may look:

- Custom - $1
- Default - $2
- Default - $3
- Custom - $4

Same with range faceting. Do you have any hints how to tackle that?
Thank you a million.

Comment: I was wondering if there is possible to use function for sorting (https://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery#Sort_By_Function) and using function something like:  `if(exists(price_[customerId]_double),price_[customerId]_double,price_double)`

Answer (score 0):

And the winner is method which I posted in comment:

```
if(exists(price_[customerId]_double),price_[customerId]_double,price_double)
```

Keep in mind that if works with boolean/integer/double values. Does not work with string and texts.